# Cake PHP - creating some kind of a mod for application

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, autoloader

I am working on outgoing dedicated project written in CakePHP, that grown quite big. The architecture uses a bunch of plugins as well. From the beginning of the project there was only one instance of this application. However Client found another area that the application can work. It will use the same codebase but separate database. The thing is that codebase is in fact applicable in about 90%, what means that in most of the time it will do its work, but there are some slight changes that are needed. After some little enhancements it is clear that those modifications will continue for this new instance. But at the same time there will be changes applicable for both instances. It wouldn't be very clean solution for making a bunch of conditions in whole application and checking which instance is actually running.

So my idea is:

- keep the project in one repository and make changes and fixes applicable for all instances in one codebase
- make some kind of "mod" that will contain classes that will overload the default classes of the project only when needed and only for the specific instance
- to make it more clear it would the best to have parallel file structure to the app directory that will contain those new classes (of course only those that are needed)
- very important thing is to not touch the cake core at all, I want be able to upgrade it anytime without problems

Example:

```
app/controllers/invoices_controller.php:
InvoicesController extends AppController {
  public function generateInvoice() {}
}

newbusinness/controllers/invoices_controller.php:
NewbusinessInvoicesController extends InvoicesController {
  public function generateInvoice() {}
}
```

What is important it when we will go to:

```
www.mynewbusinnes.com/Invoices/generateInvoice
```

the system will automatically call `NewbusinessInvoicesController->generateInvoice()`, because such child controller and method exists. Otherwise it would call default controllers and methods.

So is possible to create such mode for CakePHP, maybe on low level of loading classes? I would not like to use `runkit_method_redefine()` and replace for example the `App::import()` method, as long as `runkit_method_redefine()` is marked as "experimental". Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is possible to create such mode for CakePHP, maybe on low level of loading classes? I would not like to use runkit_method_redefine() and replace for example the App::import() method, as long as runkit_method_redefine() is marked as "experimental". Any suggestions or ideas?

All requests initially go through `app/webroot/index.php`. This file is not part of the core and can be modified by yourself. What you can do is change the [include paths](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/5ac77c2620a6f883640b1961385fd0fedb83413e/app/webroot/index.php#L68) to list a folder of your own creation before `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH`. Here I set `/absolute/path/to/custom` as an include path:

```
if (function_exists('ini_set') && ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'custom' . PATH_SEPARATOR . CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'))) {
```

Following this section, CakePHP's core bootstrap file is loaded (`/cake/bootstrap.php`) and many core classes start getting loaded:

```
require CORE_PATH . 'cake' . DS . 'basics.php';
$TIME_START = getMicrotime();
require CORE_PATH . 'cake' . DS . 'config' . DS . 'paths.php';
require LIBS . 'object.php';
require LIBS . 'inflector.php';
require LIBS . 'configure.php';
require LIBS . 'set.php';
require LIBS . 'cache.php';
Configure::getInstance();
require CAKE . 'dispatcher.php';
```

Having inserted your own include path, you can replace them by copying them to that path:

```
ROOT
|- app/
|- cake/
  |- libs/
    |- configure.php // this would usually be loaded
|- custom/
  |- cake/
    |- libs/
      |- configure.php // now this is loaded
```

(Note: the `configure.php` file contains both the `Configure` and `App` classes.)

In short, by changing a single line in `app/webroot/index.php`, you can now replace any part of CakePHP's core without editing it directly.

You may now be able to make the required changes to `App::import` but, as this isn't actually documented anywhere, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Yes this can be certainly suggestion for my solution. Obviously it must be reconsidered if it won't bring bigger confusion instead of clear and clean remedy for the situation. And that was mainly the porpouse of all this. But this seems to be what I was looking for. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1):

> So my idea is:
>
> - keep the project in one repository and make changes and fixes applicable for all instances in one codebase
> - make some kind of "mod" that will contain classes that will overload the default classes of the project only when needed and only for the specific instance
> - to make it more clear it would the best to have parallel file structure to the app directory that will contain those new classes (of course only those that are needed) - very important thing is to not touch the cake core at all, I want be able to upgrade it anytime without problems

I touched on this in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520749/wildflower-cms-is-not-a-cakephp-plugin-baked-simple-cms-is-a-cakephp-plugin/1522549#1522549), but [additional class paths](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/916/Additional-Class-Paths) sounds like it might be the CakePHP feature you are looking for. Something like the following in your "mod" app's `bootstap.php` should tell CakePHP to also load files from a `core` directory:

```
App::build(array(
    'plugins'     => array(ROOT . DS . 'core' . DS . 'plugins' . DS),
    'models'      => array(ROOT . DS . 'core' . DS . 'models' . DS),
    'views'       => array(ROOT . DS . 'core' . DS . 'views' . DS),
    'controllers' => array(ROOT . DS . 'core' . DS . 'controllers' . DS),
    'datasources' => array(ROOT . DS . 'core' . DS . 'models' . DS . 'datasources' . DS),
    'behaviors'   => array(ROOT . DS . 'core' . DS . 'models' . DS . 'behaviors' . DS),
    'components'  => array(ROOT . DS . 'core' . DS . 'controllers' . DS . 'components' . DS),
    'helpers'     => array(ROOT . DS . 'core' . DS . 'views' . DS . 'helpers' . DS),
    'vendors'     => array(ROOT . DS . 'core' . DS . 'vendors' . DS),
    'shells'      => array(ROOT . DS . 'core' . DS . 'vendors' . DS . 'shells' . DS),
    'locales'     => array(ROOT . DS . 'core' . DS . 'locale' . DS),
));
```

The above is assuming a new folder structure that, instead of `/app` and `/cake`, looks like this:

```
- ROOT
|- app1 // look here first,
|- app2
|- core // then here,
|- cake // then lastly here.
```

Comment: This can be a part of solution, hovewer I think its not exactly what I meant. I would not like to create a second app, that would take the workflow and use the original app base code. The trick is to leave the original app to handle requests and only when it would find the "mod" classes, it would replace it with them. I want to maintain whole navigation without changing the urls for actions. Still thanks for an answer.

Comment: This is the only supported way I can think of at the moment. Quick note though: you seem to be assuming that no custom modifications will be made to the original application (ie. ones you don't want appearing in the new application) - the above approach allows both applications to be extended, which may become a future requirement.